# Concatenate year to a date in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I'm trying to make a query dynamic that looks for all the dates between two days of the year (July 1 of the last year and June 30th of this year). Below is the where clause of the query I've been attempting:

```
and pbh.batch_date between
        ('30-JUN-'||extract(year from trunc(sysdate))-1))
    and ('01-JUL-'||extract(year from trunc(sysdate))))
```

This returns an inconsistent datatypes error: expected DATE got NUMBER. I then tried casting them to dates like so:

```
and pbh.batch_date between
        to_date(( '01-JUL-'||extract(year from trunc(sysdate))-1))
    and to_date(( '30-JUN-'||extract(year from trunc(sysdate))))
```

But this now returns an invalid number error. I don't know if it makes a difference what format pbh.batch_date is stored as, but it's (m)m/(d)d/yyyy

Comment: to_date needs a format to process the input string but still, @dnoeth answer is really practical

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to cast to a string and back:

```
and ph.batch_date >= add_months(trunc(sysdate,'YEAR'), -6) 
and ph.batch_date <  add_months(trunc(sysdate,'YEAR'), 6)
```

Comment: I want it to specifically be between July 1 and June 30 though. Not exactly six months either way

Comment: @Aignor: Sorry, i forgot to add the `'YEAR'`, fixed it.